# ASP Button onClick to send data from text box to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, inheritance, insert

I'm new to ASP.

I am trying to insert data from an asp:textbox into a SQL Server database.
I have created a class in the APP_CODE folder which handles the database connection and insert methods.

When button1 is clicked I want it to take the data from the asp:textbox and use the questionnaireSQL.cs file in APP_CODE to update the database.

How can I go about this?

**questionnaireSQL.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Devworks
{

    public class OscarSQL
    {
        private string _productConnectionString;
        private SqlConnection _productConn;

        public OscarSQL()
        {
            _productConn = new SqlConnection();
            _productConnectionString += "data source=mssql.dev-works.co.uk; Initial Catalog=devworks_oscar;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword";
            _productConn.ConnectionString = _productConnectionString;
        }

    // Insert New Questionnaire:

        public int InsertQuestionnaire(string QuestName, int CustomerID, int NumberOfQuest)
        {
            int retVal = 0;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("NewQuestionnaire", _productConn);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUESTNAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CUSTID", SqlDbType.Int));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NUMQUEST", SqlDbType.Int));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@QUEST_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "QUEST_ID");
            myCommand.Parameters["@QUEST_ID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            myCommand.Parameters[0].Value = QuestName;
            myCommand.Parameters[1].Value = CustomerID;
            myCommand.Parameters[2].Value = NumberOfQuest;
            _productConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            retVal = (int)myCommand.Parameters["@QUEST_ID"].Value;
            _productConn.Close();
            return retVal;
        }


        // SQL DATAREADER, DATATABLE & NON QUERY UPDATE:

        private void insert(SqlCommand myCommand)
        {
            _productConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _productConn.Close();
        }

        private SqlDataReader getData(SqlCommand myCommand)
        {
            _productConn.Open();
            SqlDataReader myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            return myDataReader;
        }

        private DataTable createDataTable(SqlDataReader data)
        {
            DataTable retVal = new DataTable();
            retVal.Load(data);
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

**newquestionnaire.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="new_questionnaire.aspx.cs" Inherits="new_questionnaire" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
            <h2 class="new">Add Your Questionnaire</h2>
            <h3>Give your questionnaire a name.</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="QuestName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <h3>CustomerID</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <h3>Number Of Questions</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="NumberOfQuest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Button  ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Create" />
        </div> <!-- end main -->
    </div> <!-- end container -->
</asp:Content>
```

**newquestionnaire.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using Devworks;

    public partial class new_questionnaire : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've posted all this code but exactly what can't you do?
One has to wonder if you wrote the  DAL (Data access layer - your db code) and the Web UI, how is it that you cannot write the click event of a button ironically called `Button1` ??

You take the value of your textbox and on the click of a button insert it into a database.
When you have a large task seperate it into smaller ones and do each piece until you've finished the puzzle.

According to your code

```
OscarSQL c = new OscarSQL(); //btw: not sure why you are not using a static class for this
int result = c.InsertQuestionnaire(textBox.Text ...);  //add all parameters here

If (result > 0) 
  //good id
else
  //display error message
```

Place all of this code behind the `button1_click` event of your code.

Comment: Thanks. This has the desired result I wanted.
my aim was to use the value from the .aspx page and parse the to a method in the .cs file in App_Code